# Raster calculator or translate with vrt output in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator, gdal-translate

I have a 1 band, 8 Bit raster. I can map all pixel values apart from 0 to 1 with the raster calculator expression `if ("rasterlayer@1"=0,0,1)`.
However, it does not seem to work with vrt output, which would be great. I have also tried the gdal raster calculator with the conditional expression `(A!=0)` with no success (`ERROR 1: Writing through VRTSourcedRasterBand is not supported.)` Same for a vrt instead of tif as input.

I can also do it by clipping the area with pixel value 0 and then applying gdal_translate with
`'EXTRA'=-b mask`, with vrt output! But when I apply this to the raster without clipping, it masks the whole area like a rectangular extend. I thought that masking means simply mapping all pixel values including 0 to 1? But when I apply `-mask 1`, it returns the raster in gray levels instead of colors:
[image]

Is there maybe a way to do this without clipping, but with vrt output?

[image: input tif file, NoData (0) set to transparent]
[image: desired output as vrt]